# Select first largest value using TOP 1 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, groupwise-maximum

I'll try to explain by example what I want to achieve in MySQL.

I have a table looking like this:

```
pricelist_id valid_from
1           1610665200000 //15 Jan 2021
2           1610751600000 //16 Jan 2021         
3           1610838000000 //17 Jan 2021
```

Values in column, `valid_from`, are essentially String values which were generated at some point in time by following Java code:

```
String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

My assignment is to pass any String value (in the format of a number, in this case `long`), generated in the same way as explained above and I need to extract single `pricelist_id` which belongs to the first lesser or equal value of `valid_from` in the table, in comparison with passed value of `valid_from`. It is hard to explain by words (and my English is just terrible), so I'll demonstrate.

If I pass a value which will represent `Jan 18th`, `1610924400000`, I would need to get single `pricelist_id` value, in this case `3`.

If I pass a value which will represent `Jan 16th 17:15:00`, `1610813700000`, I would need to get single `pricelist_id` value, in this case `2`.

If I pass a value which will represent `Jan 25th`, `1611529200000`, I would need to get single `pricelist_id` value, in this case `3`.

What I have so far, is this:

```
select  max(p.pricelist_id)
from pricelist p
where  (p.valid_from + 0) <= some_passed_value
order by p.valid_from, p.pricelist_id desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rely on `pricelist_id` being in the exact same sort order as `valid_from`, then your solution using `max()` works.

Otherwise you can use LIMIT:

```
select  p.pricelist_id
from pricelist p
where  (p.valid_from + 0) <= some_passed_value
order by p.valid_from, p.pricelist_id desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to number for ordering and for comparing
Also use limit to get the higher value

select  p.pricelist_id
from pricelist p
where  CONVERT(p.valid_from, SIGNED) <= some_passed_value
order by CONVERT(p.valid_from, SIGNED), p.pricelist_id desc
LIMIT 0, 1